# Matplotlib on mac OSX, python 3.6 inconsistent and extremely brittle

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

I don't get why matplotlib continues to just suck really, really hard on Mac. We put a man on the moon but...

Excuse my frustration it's just really annoying. I do not know why it continues to torment.

I am on Mac OSX, Sierra, 10.12.6, using Python 3.6.7, and matplotlib version 3.0.2.

When I run the following command,

```
plt.imshow(image, interpolation=None, cmap = "gray"); plt.show()
```

The plot shows up, but the zooming in and out are SUPER inconsistent. Sometimes the zoom works. Sometimes it doesn't. Sometimes the zooming out works. Sometimes it doesn't. If I come to close the window showing the plot, it just sits there, and doesn't go away. I eventually just have to exit the entire program.

How can I get zooming consistent in this scenario?

Thanks

Comment: Note that (1) many problems people experience on macs are due to macs, (2) The NASA put less money into flying to the moon than Apple is worth (3) matplotlib is used by the NASA in some applications. (4) The Nasa does not use macs. This being said, have you tried a different backend?

Comment: Can you clarify 'inconsistent zooming', I have literally never seen this issue before.  But then again I only use it on windows / linux.

Comment: Personally I don't experience any issues while running the code and I haven't had too much trouble with matplotlib in the past. Since it looks like you are displaying an image, if it is really an issue, you could potentially switch over to [opencv](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html).

Comment: You may want to also try `interpolation="bicubic"` or `interpolation="nearest"`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I do not believe I have tried a different backend... I am not sure where to start on that?....

Comment: @GlobalTraveler So there is a zoom icon which you can click on, and then your mouse becomes a plus which you can use to zoom. However being inconsistent means that it doesn't do that... or something does... if I manage to zoom, cant zoom out... I press the home icon and nothing happens,.. just freezes...

Comment: You would set a backend via `import matplotlib; matplotlib.use("Qt5Agg")` in the first line of the script. Possible alternatives to `"Qt5Agg"` are seen [here](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#backends).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest May you please make this an answer? I will have to try it out anyway... any other ideas?

Comment: You can try another backend as @ImportanceOfBeingEarnest says. Qt5 / Qt4. I am assuming this is an issue with the backend and not necessarily with matplotlib per se.

Comment: oh and i forget to add you may want to check which versions of the backend you are running. I had issues with spyder before and downgrading fixed a lot of issues

Comment: @GlobalTraveler Oh interesting. How can I check what versions of the backend I am using? Why do you bring up Spyder? What version do you use?

Comment: I had odd issues with spyder not starting while I was installing it through conda. I couldn't really figure out what the issue was until I read on a forum somewhere that it was recommended to pyqt5.6. This magically fixed it for me. I find it unlikely that your input device is causing issues as I haven ever heard macusers complain about this. Hence I suspect it is your backend that is causing the issue. You can check the backend with; matplotlib.get_backend().